# Error sim_vehicle.py Ardupilot: ../../libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS.cpp: In member function ‘void AP_GPS::send_mavlink_gps2_raw(mavlink_channel_t)’

Tags: python, drone.io

My goal is to simulate the ArduCopter in Gazebo, I am on Linux Ubuntu 20.04. After building the setup for Ardupilot like in the description:

https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/building-setup-linux.html#building-setup-linux

I am using the following commands:

```
~git checkout Copter-4.0.4
~git submodule update --init --recursive
~cd ~/ardupilot/Tools/autotest
~python sim_vehicle.py -w -v ArduCopter
```

the build always fails at [136/642] with the following error message:

```
[135/642] Compiling libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS_SBP2.cpp
[136/642] Compiling libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS_SIRF.cpp
../../libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS.cpp: In member function ‘void AP_GPS::send_mavlink_gps2_raw(mavlink_channel_t)’:
../../libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS.cpp:1168:24: error: too few arguments to function ‘void mavlink_msg_gps2_raw_send(mavlink_channel_t, uint64_t, uint8_t, int32_t, int32_t, int32_t, uint16_t, uint16_t, uint16_t, uint16_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint32_t, uint16_t, int32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t)’
 1168 |         gps_yaw_cdeg(1));
      |                        ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Waf: Leaving directory `/home/nicole/ardupilot/build/sitl'
Build failed
 -> task in 'objs/AP_GPS' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 140291281115616: cxx AP_GPS.cpp -> AP_GPS.cpp.0.o}
 (run with -v to display more information)
SIM_VEHICLE: Build failed
SIM_VEHICLE: Killing tasks
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That seems like mismatching versions of the libraries. (Yes, an outdated question)

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same error, using g++-6 and python2.7 did not work. Turns out the problem is in checking out the latest Copter build, its not 4.0.4 but 4.4, the following code shall work:

```
~cd ~/ardupilot
~git checkout Copter-4.0.4 
~git submodule update --init --recursive
~cd ~/ardupilot/Tools/autotest
~python3 sim_vehicle.py -w -v ArduCopter
```